# What standard design pattern or concept is this?

Tags: oop, design-patterns, model

**Question:** If I had a model object, call it `Employee`, and I wanted to expose different views of the `Person` object depending on the consumer of the object: `ManagerEmployeeView`, `EmployeeEmployeeView`, or `OwnerEmployeeView`.

What is this pattern called? Is it any good? What are the standard nomenclatures associated with such designs? I ask so that I don't reinvent the wheel.

**Purpose:** After modeling an object, I want to expose different "views" to consumers such that I only give them what they need and nothing more -- for security's sake and other purposes. The so called "views" are not to be mistaken with MVC views, i.e., it does not render anything, it is only a model.

**Thoughts:** The models are rich model, not anemic, thus the views not only abstract properties but also provide different behaviors. I would like to know if there are similar approaches so that I can learn from them. Naming styles for such an approach/models is more than appreciated, even though it may be considered subjective, I feel as though proper naming is an important step to master the idea. `ViewModels` come to mind as a solution, but call it cargo cult, `ViewModels` are usually employed as a model for a view (UI) and not a "model for a model" (if that makes any sense) -- correct me if I'm wrong.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: [Model-view-viewmodel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93viewmodel)?

Comment: I’m thinking more of a Model View close to an RDBMS like view instead of a presentation view model which is made for data binding with a presentation layer.

Comment: "The models are rich model, not anemic, thus the views not only abstract properties but also provide different behaviors". Could you give some behavior examples? It seems that you are trying to solve behavioral security and data query security using different concrete class implementations, which is probably not the right overall approach. Queries do not belong in the domain model and while security rules might, they are often extracted to the application layer.

Comment: @plalx A simple example is, if a manager can see an employee’s salary then their view of the employee object would have the salary property as well as related methods such as calculateWagePerHour and etc - domain specific behaviors, does not include external service such as persistence. A peer employees view of another employee would be one that did not have salary or salary related methods. The application layer does the heavy lifting but delegates business logic of a domain to said domain model. Correct me if such an approach is not recommended.

Comment: If you want to expose objects from a class with a different interface `Adapter/Wrapper` pattern comes to mind (you have just called the new interfaces `views`) but @plalx comment looks quite relevant too.

Comment: @progmatico adapter pattern may explain the behavior I'm describing. It is not that I disagree with plalx, but rather I don't think his observation is pertinent to what I'm trying to understand. One thing he comments is about is that I'm trying to solve data query security in my domain model, which I am not and don't think I am suggesting. I more concerned about the payload I give to consumers being relevant to their needs - a design pattern akin to how RDBMS implement views. RDBMS have records with one model, but can have other views for the record. Adapter seems closer, thx for comment.

Comment: What's the consumer (e.g. which class and in which conceptual layer)? You want to expose different application service contracts based on the role of the client? I have never really seen security concerns dealt with using this approach, but I guess it could work. It wouldn't be the adapter pattern though, given all adapters should seamlessly provide the same features to all clients. It's a form of [interface segregation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interface_segregation_principle) I guess.

Comment: The consumer I believe can be any external domain. Whether it be a different domain model, application plugin or client over network. The consumer is anything interested in using the domain model. Is that crazy? I’m questioning my sanity every time I think of the approach

Comment: Are the `views` conceptually seen as part of the domain model or the application layer? If they are part of the domain I think this would be wrong, given it introduces new names that aren't part of the UL as a technical implementation detail to enforce security. If it's part of the application layer I guess it may be fine, but I'm not a fan of building the whole security model around roles which is overly limiting. What if you have some rule-based security that creeps into this? It will become a mess given roles would be at the center of your entire design.

Comment: @plalx great point on your last sentence. I'll rethink my approach.